# How to use guacamole for secondary development of sftp

Tags: java, sftp, remote-desktop, guacamole

I want to make secondary development through guacamole.
Now through the [demo](https://github.com/apache/guacamole-client/tree/master/doc), I know how to create a connection and play back the screen file. The demo is very helpful to me.
In addition, I want to use guacamole's sftp for file transfer.

I would like to ask if there is a way for my secondary development interface to use ‘ctrl+alt+shift’ to pop up the left action box, or use guacamole's sftp api in other ways.

Does guacamole provide sftp api ?

Answer (score 0):

There is not really an SFTP API, but there is API for accessing remote files in the forms of the Streams. The Guacamole can map files either using SFTP or by using drive redirection for RDP. In any case, the stream makes an abstraction layer for file transfer. Details on usage can be found in the API: https://guacamole.apache.org/doc/guacamole-common-js/

Regarding opening left side menu, it should be possible to open it programmatically from a Guacamole extension.